# Make sure that only a Scheduled Task can call a Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, scheduled-tasks

My ASP.NET MVC 4 website has a Controller Action that will be called by a Scheduled Task once every 30 minutes. I am using this in place of a service for convenience.

The Action will perform some essential admin tasks and I want to ensure that only this scheduled task can call it. The Scheduled Task will call `www.mywebsite.com/Admin/PerformAdmin`, which can be seen below.

```
public ActionResult PerformAdmin()
{
     // Only allow IP of my own server in
     if(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] == "192.145.5.52") {
          // Do admin tasks
     }
     return View();
}
```

This is one way that I think will work but it seems messy. Is there a more reliable, proven method to restrict Controller access to an automated call like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the IP-address you could use a [shared-secret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_secret) between the controller and the scheduled task. This way if the ip address ever changes you should still be able to connect.

The main concept is that you have some password, long passphrase or random combination of characters that is only known between the sender and the receiver. You will need to ensure to have a an encrypted connection so that it is impossible to sniff the shared secret.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great idea. By secure connection do you mean that the request is sent via HTTPS instead of HTTP?